# Остановка выполнения js скрипта при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Есть лендинг. На первом блоке огромный скрипт, который на канвасе отрисовывает всякую чепуху. Следовательно все это жрет ресурс и на слабых машинах подвисает. Возникло желание останавливать этот скрипт, когда уходит из поля видимости первый блок страницы. Чтобы оно вообще прекращало там рисовать.

Comment: ТС, т.е. ты, вот ты вопрос переформулировал, а мой ответ по-прежнему актуален. Я не знаю что туда добавить. Если тебе нужно чего-то большее - то давай сюда этот свой огромный скрипт, ща мы тебе его остановим. Или сам попробуй, с чего начать я написал (поищи в нем requestAnimationFrame - это должен быть основной animation loop, но не обязательно, есть и другие варианты.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я переформулировал чтобы уж не казалось, что я задаю 2 разных вопроса. Сейчас копаю в сторону вашей подсказки.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.onscroll=function(){    
    if( document.body.scrollTop > header.offsetTop+header.offsetHeight ) $.animation.stop();
    else $.animation.sdelat_zbs();
}
```

Comment: Какие ваши доказательства? :)

Comment: Каков вопрос таков ответ..

Comment: Нажмите f12, замените $.animation.stop() на alert('stop') и погоняйте на шапке stackoverflow, у меня работает

Comment: Не аргумент. Если вопрос не понятен, стоит задать уточняющие вопросы. В текущей редакции уже лучше. Хотя бы видна основная идея

Comment: Ну да, я забыл перевести на js "при прокрутке" в первом варианте

Comment: Только у ТС появится вопрос как потом анимацию опять запускать, но если сам не справится, он наверное спросит

Comment: о черт.. щас добавлю

Comment: ТС, т.е. я, вообще некорректно сформулировал вопрос. Сейчас объясню. Есть лендинг. На первом блоке огромный скрипт, который на канвасе отрисовывает всякую чепуху. Следовательно все это жрет ресурс и на слабых машинах подвисает. Возникло желание останавливать этот скрипт, когда уходит из поля видимости первый блок страницы. Чтобы оно вообще нафик прекращало там рисовать.

Comment: и вы не знаете где у этого огромного скрипта .stop() ? Рекомендую начинать поиски с ctrl-F `requestAnimationFrame`